# Уменьшить количество блоков flex-box

Tags: css, css3, html5

[image: Это - эмуляция экрана телефона]

Реализация: `flex`

Можно ли чисто теоретически сделать так чтобы на телефонных девайсах этих блоков было меньше, скажем 5: Один - по центру и по два блока слева и справа?

Я думаю, что единственное решение это в `@media` запросах писать `display: none`, определенным блокам, что скажете?

Comment: Скажем, что вообще ничего непонятно...

Comment: @Qwertiy, блоки похожие на кирпичики видишь?

Comment: Вам думается правильно, задавайте определенным блокам через @media none, а для других по 2 с каждой - можно их по % width выровнять например.

Comment: на habrahabr есть статейка где сравнивают css-table и flexbox  и дело в том что flex не лучше чем `display:table;` https://habrahabr.ru/post/281254/

Comment: @Geyan, с костылями сравнение же, но все равно спасибо)

Comment: @Legionary http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/amkrgg  маленький пример

Answer (score 2):

По-быстрому набросал на основе flex и css pseudo-selectors.
http://codepen.io/AlexeyNovik/pen/PGBpXw

```
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>

div{
  background-color: red;
  min-width:40px;
  min-height:100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div div{
  background-color:blue;
  margin:5px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  div div:nth-child(-n+3), div div:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    display:none;
  }
}
```